# Intel® Dynamic Platform and Thermal Framework (DPTF) for Linux

Tags: linux, linux-mint, intel-core-i7

I have a new laptop with Core i7 7th Gen, and since no Windows other than 10 work on 7th Gen Intel, I decided to switch completely to Linux.

I was going through all drivers for Windows that was given in the CD that came with Laptop, and there is one driver called "DPTF", which far as I read is not implemented in Linux Kernel.

Google took me to https://github.com/01org/dptf , where there's detailed instruction on how to compile the code, with minor glitches.

In light of that,

1. Will getting it set up on Linux benefit me in any way?
2. If it does, from README.md of git, under instructions for Ubuntu (I'm using Linux Mint 18.1)

   - > Run make under /ESIF/Products/ESIF_UF/Linux to build
     >   the esif_ufd executable.

   running make with that directory in focus gives a series of errors,

> `++++ 
>   ++++ ESIF_UF x64 Release Linux GMIN=1
>   ++++ 
>   gcc -c -Wno-multichar -Werror -fPIE -fPIC -O2 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Wformat-security -fstack-protector-strong -m64  -I../../ESIF_UF/Sources -I../../ESIF_CM/Sources -I../../ESIF_WS/Sources -I../../ESIF_LIB/Sources -I../../../../Common -DESIF_ATTR_USER  -DESIF_ATTR_DAEMON -DESIF_ATTR_OS_LINUX -DESIF_ATTR_OS_LINUX_HAVE_READLINE  -DESIF_FEAT_OPT_ACTION_SYSFS -o ../../ESIF_UF/Sources/lin/main.o ../../ESIF_UF/Sources/lin/main.c
>   In file included from ../../../../Common/esif_ccb_sort.h:29:0,
>                    from ../../../../Common/esif_ccb_file_lin_user.h:100,
>                    from ../../../../Common/esif_ccb_file.h:28,
>                    from ../../ESIF_CM/Sources/esif.h:198,
>                    from ../../ESIF_UF/Sources/esif_uf.h:22,
>                    from ../../ESIF_UF/Sources/lin/main.c:27:
>   ../../../../Common/esif_ccb_file_lin_user.h: In function ‘esif_ccb_file_enum_first’:
>   ../../../../Common/esif_ccb_sort_lin_user.h:60:48: error: implicit declaration of function ‘qsort_r’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
>    #define esif_ccb_qsort(bas, num, siz, fn, ctx) qsort_r(bas, num, siz, fn, ctx)
>                                                   ^
>   ../../../../Common/esif_ccb_file_lin_user.h:169:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘esif_ccb_qsort’
>      esif_ccb_qsort(find_handle->files, find_handle->matches, sizeof(char *), esif
>      ^
>   cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
>   Makefile:180: recipe for target '../../ESIF_UF/Sources/lin/main.o' failed
>   make: *** [../../ESIF_UF/Sources/lin/main.o] Error 1`

How to fix this?

Comment: For second bit of it, I could fix it by adding `CPPFLAGS += -std=gnu89` in /ESIF/Products/ESIF_UF/Linux/Makefile

Comment: The README clearly states that the framework is for Chromium OS, which uses a modified Linux kernel. The first step also clearly mentions entering Chromium SDK's chroot environment. Thus, the software in question is not made for standard desktop Linux kernels and environment.

Comment: @Larssend, scroll down.

Comment: Okay, my bad then.